# Unable to display object properties when the object seems to be defined (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have some code in a MERN stack app where users can enter another user's name into a search bar, and the webpage will return other properties of the user whose name they searched up.

For example, if I search up "John Doe" in the search bar, it should return something like this in the front end:

```
Name: John Doe
Age: 30
Sex: Male
```

Here is the code for the React component I made to handle this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../styles/styles.css";

function SearchUser() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);

  async function getUsers(query) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/auth/userSearch?fullName=${query}`);
    setUser(response.data);
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!searchQuery) {
      setFormError(true);
      return;
    }

    setFormError(false);
    getUsers(searchQuery);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="create-profile-border">
        <h1>Search a user</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter a user's full name here"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={searchQuery}
            />
            {formError && !searchQuery && (
              <p className="error-message">This is a required field</p>
            )}
          </div>
          <button className="create-profile-button" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>

        {user.fullName > 0 && (
          <div>
            <p>Name: {user.fullName}</p>
            <p>Age: {user.age}</p>
            <p>Sex: {user.sex}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default SearchUser;
```

I have checked and confirmed that the backend code is working properly, the issue purely lies in the frontend.

**The Issue I have:**

After debugging and some console logging, it seems that user.fullName/user.age/user.email are all undefined. However, in this console log:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect[user]:", JSON.stringify(user));
  }, [user]);
```

I get back a user object in the browser console when I type "John Doe" in the search bar:

```
effect[user]: {"user":{"_id":"63eea67c0316be96ebf799f0","email":"johndoe@example.com","passwordHash":"DU7fwnIlucrwT7R","fullName":"John Doe","age":"30","sex":"male","__v":0}}
```

I suspect there's some funny business with the rendering but as I'm still inexperienced with React, I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's that `politician:` at the start of your console object? Is your `user` in fact an object whose only key is `politican`, whose corresponding value is the object you need?

Comment: @RobinZigmond mb, I was asking this question while working on some other project too so my brain got it mixed up, it should be "user", no "politician" present

Comment: edited the post accordingly to fix the typo

Comment: well OK, but if your console output is that it suggests that you need eg `user.user.email` rather than `user.email`

Comment: you have `politician.fullName`while it's not declared anywhere, shouldn't you use `user` there? Or I'm missing something

Comment: @Phil I mistyped the code--edited it accordingly. Same issue persists with `user.fullName > 0`

Comment: @Fcmam5 Not missing anything, it was a typo on my end--in my actual code I have it as `user.fullName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I subscribe to all the suggestions from phil. However, after looking at the log from your console, I think your data is returned as a user. so you should be able to get the data by setting user to response.data.user

```
async function getUsers(query) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/auth/userSearch?fullName=${query}`);
    setUser(response.data.user);
  }
```

or

```
const getUsers = async (fullName) => {
  setUser(
    (
      await axios.get("/auth/userSearch", {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/", // even better, use your .env file
        params: { fullName },
      })
    ).data.user
  );
};
```

Comment: Yep! You were exactly right, response.data.user did the trick. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is trying to compare the **string** property `user.fullName` to numeric `0`. Unless your string is purely numeric, `user.fullName > 0` will always be `false`.

Instead of initialising `user` to be an empty object, try starting it with `null`. Then you can more easily test if it has a value or not...

```jsx
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

// ...

{user && (
  <div>
    <p>Name: {user.fullName}</p>
    <p>Age: {user.age}</p>
    <p>Sex: {user.sex}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

---

Another improvement you can make is to employ Axios' `params` option to correctly encode URL query parameters.

*Update:* after prompting you to debug your own API response, it also seems your response data is nested under a `user` property

```js
const getUsers = async (fullName) => {
  setUser(
    (
      await axios.get("/auth/userSearch", {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/", // even better, use your .env file
        params: { fullName },
      })
    ).data.user //  extract the `user` property
  );
};
```

[image: Edit compassionate-gwen-ztvy8x]

Comment: Thanks for your axios tips.
I set `const [user, setUser] = useState(null)`
and changed `user.fullName > 0` to just `user`.
Issue still persist however. When I `console.log(user)` in `handleSubmit`, I get back `null`. However, when I `console.log(user)` under `useEffect()` I get the proper user object returned. Know what's causing that?

Comment: Why are you logging your state values? There's no need to and [the results are often confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/283366) for developers new to React. I'd suggest using better debugging tools like the [React Dev Tools](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/react-developer-tools) browser extension and that's only if you actually need to do any debugging

Comment: I'm getting still `null` values for `user`. What's the error in my logic? Bear in mind I've tested out my backend a ton so I know for a fact that the issue isn't with the router. When the submit button is clicked, `handleSubmit` is ran that runs `getUsers`, which in turn sets the `user` object based on the search query. If my backend is returning the correct `user` when a search is queried, what did I do wrong in my front-end code?

Comment: Can you change your effect hook logger to use `console.log("effect[user]:", JSON.stringify(user))` like in my CodeSandbox link? Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75488997/edit) your question with the details

Comment: Edited my post accordingly

Comment: @God'sDrunkestDriver so the original data you presented wasn't actually what your data looks like? Aren't you in control of the API response? Shouldn't you have known the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the full JSON response from your API? I'm asking because what you pasted *seems* to imply the response looks something like this:

```json
{
  user: { _id: "...", email: "...", passwordHash: "..." },
  _id: "63eea67c0316be96ebf799f0"
  fullName: "John Doe"
​​  age: "30"
}
```

Said another way... Based on your paste, the `data.user` object does not contain the `fullName` property, but rather `data.fullName` does.

Comment: I edited my post to show the JSON.stringify(user) in the console log, if that would help.